# Ganache UI: how to run in deterministic mode?

Tags: ganache

Ganache CLI has a deterministic mode switch

```
$ ganache-cli --deterministic
```

Does Ganache UI has the same switch?

I have searched the UI thoroughly but cannot find a button to click.

If UI indeed is missing this feature, what other features UI are missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Right corner you can see the save button if you save it then it will act as a deterministic mode[image]

Comment: Thank you Dinesh. Clicking "SAVE" saves a workspace - default to OPEN-TRADE. Next time when I launch ganache, I select "OPEN-TRADE" workspace. This brings back the same set of addresses.